# Conversion of string to DateTime & using conversion in Where Clause - DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string column that contains dates. I want to convert string to date so that i can use the Date Logic ahead.

I have converted the string to DateTime but while applying the logic in the Where clause it doesn't allow me to use the Column.

```
SELECT a.code,       
       CONVERT(DATETIME,b.[FieldValue],103) as [Date1]           
FROM   [dbo].employeedetail as A join [dbo].CustomeFieldDetail as B
on A.Id = B.EMployeeid
WHERE  a.empstatus = 1 
 AND B.CustomeFieldName = 'PASSPORT' AND
       ( Datediff(dd, Getdate(), Dateadd(yyyy, Datediff(yyyy, b.[Date1], 
         Getdate()) 
                + 
                1, b.[Date1])) 
         + 1 ) % 366 = 50
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just use same conversion expression in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: _I have a string column that contains dates._ - this is should be first sign, that you will have problems and if you  not fixing it now you will have more problems later, especially when you do calculations in sql queries.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 3):

Use APPLY to introduce a reusable expression.

```
SELECT a.code,       
       c.[Date1]           
FROM  [dbo].employeedetail as A 
JOIN  [dbo].CustomeFieldDetail as B ON A.Id = B.EMployeeid
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,b.[FieldValue],103) as [Date1] 
) c
WHERE  a.empstatus = 1 
 AND B.CustomeFieldName = 'PASSPORT' AND
       ( Datediff(dd, Getdate(), Dateadd(yyyy, Datediff(yyyy, c.[Date1], 
         Getdate()) 
                + 
                1, c.[Date1])) 
         + 1 ) % 366 = 50
```

A better solution is store dates as DATE, DATETIME, not strings.

Comment: It gives me error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: @Anup , Check if `b.[FieldValue]` conforms to format 103.

Comment: values are in dd/MM/yyyy format. I am getting the Error in Where Clause DateDiff section. If i erase the DateDiff condition then the Query is running.

Comment: @Anup .. I see no character string arguments in the `Datediiff` expression in WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

Using CTE results in an even more compact query:

```
WITH B AS (
    SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME, [FieldValue], 103) AS [Date1]
    FROM [dbo].CustomeFieldDetail
    WHERE (CustomeFieldName = 'PASSPORT')
)
SELECT A.code, B.[Date1]
FROM [dbo].EmployeeDetail AS A JOIN B ON A.Id = B.EMployeeid
WHERE (A.empstatus = 1)
  AND (((DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), 
         DATEADD(yyyy, DATEDIFF(yyyy, B.[Date1], GETDATE()) + 1, B.[Date1])) + 1)
        % 366) = 50)
```